# Youden's J statistic can be negative but it is said to be between 0 and 1

Tags: measurement, information-retrieval

J = (true_positives x  true_negatives - false_positives x false_negatives)  / (positives x negatives)

where positives and negatives are the number of real positive and real negative samples.

```
Its value ranges from 0 through 1 (inclusive)
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youden%27s_J_statistic

This is simply a result of assuming that the test/classifier performs better than with its answers swapped. As it is said in [the original paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/1097-0142%281950%293%3A1%3C32%3A%3AAID-CNCR2820030106%3E3.0.CO%3B2-3) (Youden, 1950):

```
1. The possible range of values for the 
index is from zero to one inclusive. (It is 
expected that the test will show a greater 
proportion of positive results for the diseased 
group than for the control.)
```

But theoretically Youden's J statistic can be negative and whether the test/classifier needs class-swapping that's another issue I would say.

Why is this assumption assumed by default? For me it is not so obvious.